# c# DataTable: More efficient Group By and Sum?

Tags: c#, datatable, group-by, sum

I merge two similar tables, where I have 2 fields (ID and Quantity) and end up with a table where I can have multiple records for the same ID. I want the resulting table to have only 1 record for each ID, while SUMMING the respective Quantities for each ID. After long Google search I came up with this code:

```
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Table1");
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Table2");

    dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
    dt1.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Int32));
    dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1 });
    dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 2 });
    dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 3 });
    dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 4 });

    dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
    dt2.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Int32));
    dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 100 });
    dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 100 });
    dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 100 });

    dt1.Merge(dt2);

    var datas = dt1.AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["ID"] })
       .Select(g => g.First()["Quantity"] = g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x["Quantity"].ToString())))
       .ToList();

    dt1 = dt1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["ID"] })
        .Select(x => x.First()).CopyToDataTable();
```

However, I feel that there is a way to do this more efficiently as the table gets scanned twice in this case. Does anyone have any suggestions?

One more thing, as a bonus question I would like to find a total Quantity across the entire resulting table, idealy in an efficient way (that is WHILE grouping it).

**UPDATE:** yes I know, DataTable is not a wise data structure, but due to the nature of our project I am forced to work with them. I would much appreciate a suggestion on how to use an intermediary data structure here but in the end I need a DataTable.

Comment: Well, it can be done by various ways. For example, you can get rid of linq approach and scan your table in a single loop while summing quantities in separate `Dictionary<int, int>` having IDs as keys and quantities as values.

Comment: I would just get the data sorted and make a simple loop going through both at the same time and summing if needed. Or if there's a lot of data and sorting would take time, then Andy's comment is good. Also would allow getting the total easily. This is one example where a few lines of code works nicer than LINQ (though someone might come up with a LINQ version also). On another note, DataTables are quite bad at performance, so if you have a huge dataset they're not the best.

Comment: why are you using datatables, they suck

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen what data structure would you suggest then? I receive my DataTable-s as a result of an SQL-request (that is the nature of our project) but for the final step I need to merge them. We decided that making the original SQL request bigger is not wise, therefore I will need to convert the DataTable into some other structure first. So what would you suggest? Also I would love a link to a code exaple for the dictionary approach.

Comment: @cubrman You have to add pairs to the Dictionary and can only acquire the "Quantity" using the "ID" (not the other way around, which fits your requirements I guess, if that's what you wanted to know).

`Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

dict.Add(1,100); int quantity = dict[1];`

Comment: So input are Datatables, output is one Datatable? How big can the Datatables be?

Comment: Instead of retrieving the raw data and trying to group in memory, the fastest way would be to use a SQL statement to do the grouping. DataTables are *not* bad structures if you want to use their features (eg multiple indexes, calculated fields). In this case though, you are trying to do what the database could do best.

Comment: @cubrman I usually use just data objects on a list for example. I don't do much filtering, queries etc that DataTables would provide that I can't do as efficiently on a simpler structure. They have a lot of overhead in them.

Comment: Data tables are in memory. They should be blindingly fast compared to disk IO and network IO. Are you really getting any benefit here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//your method
public void YourMethod()
{
     Dictionary<int, int> result = new Dictionary<int, int>();

     int length = 0;

     if(dt1.Rows.Count > dt2.Rows.Count)
        length = dt1.Rows.Count
     else
         length = dt2.Rows.Count

     for(int i=0; i < length - 1; i++)
     {
         AddRowValue(dt1, result, i);
         AddRowValue(dt2, result, i);
     }  

}


public AddRowValue(DataTable tbl, Dictionary<int, int> dic, int index)
{
    if( index > tbl.Rows.Count)
       return;

    DataRow row = tbl.Rows[index];

    int idValue = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]);
    int quantityValue = Convert.ToInt32(row["Quantity"]);

    if(dic.Keys.Contains(idValue)
         dic[idValue] = dic[idValue] + quantityValue;
    else
         dic.Add(idValue, quantityValue);
}
```

You need something like this, you can use dictionary at the end the result will be stored in the dictionary.

Comment: Loading the dictionary will kill any performance benefits. Grouping does the *same* thing after all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure how group by works under the linq, but here at least you are using it once. In his code he makes 2 group by. He can easily check which approach is better with stop watch.

Comment: @mybirthname to make the answer complete, you need to add code, that updates the initial table to include ALL unique IDs ONCE and with correct Quantity sum.

Comment: It is not needed to use datatable anymore, he can use dictionary.

Comment: I don't see anything missed, please don't think, try it, if you don't want ignore the answer. We are scanning both tables with one loop.

Comment: @mybirthname I ended up using your solution anyway - linq is too convoluted.